# How to create a colorbar from a linear segmented colormap in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am creating a bar chart where the bars are colored according to a custom colormap to display an extra dimension of data. I used linearsegmentedcolormap to create the colors. The code looks something like this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

xvalues = [1,2,3,4]
yvalues = [1,2,3,4]
colorvalues = [0,0.3,0.6,0.99]

clist = [(0, 'powderblue'), (1, 'darkblue')]
colors = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", clist)

barcolors = []
for value in colorvalues:
    barcolors.append(colors(value))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(xvalues, yvalues, color = barcolors)
```

This all works how I want it to and produces the graph I am looking for. However, I also want to add a colorbar legend using the colors produced by the linearsegmentedcolormap. Whenever I try to use plt.colorbar as shown below

```
plt.colorbar(colors)
```

I get an error stating
AttributeError: 'LinearSegmentedColormap' object has no attribute 'autoscale_None'

The solutions I have found that create a custom colormap using the linearsegmentedcolormap method have used the said colormap on the graph itself using something like plt.imshow. I have not been able to find a solution where the colormap is not actually used to graph something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try creating a cmap mappable object based on your colors and draw the colorbar from it:

```
## you other codes go here

from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
cmappable = ScalarMappable(norm=Normalize(0,1), cmap=colors)
plt.colorbar(cmappable)
```

Output:

[image]